# NullPointerException when working with Coprocessor in HBASE?

Tags: hadoop, nullpointerexception, hbase

I am using HBASE 0.94.8 with HDFS.I have Implemented Co-processor for Summation of values.The table has only two rows

> hbase(main):043:0> scan 'demo'
>
> ROW                  COLUMN+CELL
>
> row1                              column=info:category,
>   timestamp=1375438808010, value=web
>   row1                              column=info:hits,
>   timestamp=1375438797824, value=123
>   row2                              column=info:category,
>   timestamp=1375438834518,value=mail
>   row2                              column=info:hits,
>   timestamp=1375438822093, value=1321

hbase(main):043:0> describe 'demo'

> 'demo', {METHOD => 'table_att', coprocessor$1 =>
>   '|org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocess true
>   or.AggregateImplementation||'}, {NAME => 'info', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING
>   => 'NONE', BLOO                                                 MFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '3',
>   COMPRESSION => 'NONE',
>   MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => '2147483647', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS =>
>   'false', BLOCKSIZE                                                  =>
>   '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', ENCODE_ON_DISK => 'true', BLOCKCACHE =>
>   'true'}                                                   1 row(s) in
>   0.0670 seconds

MY code is given below:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.KeyValue; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.coprocessor.AggregationClient; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.coprocessor.LongColumnInterpreter;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.ColumnInterpreter; 
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.CoprocessorHost;
```

> ```
> public class webAggregator {
>
>    // private static final byte[] EDRP_FAMILY = Bytes.toBytes("EDRP");
>    // private static final byte[] EDRP_QUALIFIER = Bytes.toBytes("advanceKWh");
>    public static void testSumWithValidRange(Configuration conf,
>                  String[] otherArgs) throws Throwable {
>           byte[] EDRP_TABLE = Bytes.toBytes(otherArgs[0]);
>           byte[] EDRP_FAMILY = Bytes.toBytes(otherArgs[1]);
>           byte[] EDRP_QUALIFIER = Bytes.toBytes(otherArgs[2]);
>
>           conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "master");
>           conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2222");
>
>           conf.setLong("hbase.rpc.timeout", 600000);
>
>           conf.setLong("hbase.client.scanner.caching", 1000);
>           conf.set(CoprocessorHost.REGION_COPROCESSOR_CONF_KEY,
>                        "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.AggregateImplementation");
>
>           // Utility.CreateHBaseTable(conf, otherArgs[1], otherArgs[2], true);
>           /*HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
>           HTableDescriptor desc = new HTableDescriptor(EDRP_TABLE);
>           desc.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(EDRP_FAMILY));
>           admin.createTable(desc);*/
>
>           AggregationClient aClient = new AggregationClient(conf);
>           Scan scan = new Scan();
>           scan.addColumn(EDRP_FAMILY, EDRP_QUALIFIER);
>
>
>           HTable table = new HTable(conf, "demo");
>           Scan s = new Scan();
>           ResultScanner ss = table.getScanner(s);
>           for(Result r:ss){
>               for(KeyValue kv : r.raw()){
>                  System.out.print(new String(kv.getRow()) + " ");
>                  System.out.print(new String(kv.getFamily()) + ":");
>                  System.out.print(new String(kv.getQualifier()) + " ");
>                  System.out.print(kv.getTimestamp() + " ");
>                  System.out.println(new String(kv.getValue()));
>               }
>           }
>
>           final ColumnInterpreter<Long, Long> ci = new LongColumnInterpreter();
>           long sum = aClient.sum(Bytes.toBytes(otherArgs[0]), ci, scan);
>           System.out.println(sum);
>    }
>
>    /**
>    * Main entry point.
>    *
>    * @param argsThe
>    *            command line parameters.
>    * @throws Exception
>    *             When running the job fails.
>    */
>    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
>      Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
>        String[] otherArgs ={"demo","info","hits"};
>       try {
>          testSumWithValidRange(conf, otherArgs);
>        } catch (Throwable e) {
>          e.printStackTrace();
>        }
>    } }
> ```

MY stack trace is given below:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at webAggregator.testSumWithValidRange(webAggregator.java:62)
>           at webAggregator.main(webAggregator.java:79)

Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error with you. After some investigation, I find the problem is my column type is integer, so the LongColumnInterpreter.getValue method returns null.

From your code and result, I am sure that your 'info:hits' column is a string column but not a long column.

Just consider to change hits to real long column , from hbase shell its value should look like

```
11Ak8Z4Mswtk00:MXf1NZ                        column=f1:dp, timestamp=1400144073173, value=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00b
```

Or you can write a ColumnInterpreter yourself to handle string value sum.

Comment: how can you make sure that it's stored as a real long?

Answer (score 0):

The question is about the data type.

```
A. put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("objects"), Bytes.toBytes("info"), Bytes.toBytes(1.0));
```

`max/min/sum` is OK.
But

```
B. put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("objects"), Bytes.toBytes("info"), Bytes.toBytes("1.0"));
```

It is not OK.
And from hbase-shell, we can see

```
A. column=objects:info, timestamp=1525942759312, value=?\xF0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
B. column=objects:info, timestamp=1525941054901, value=1.0
```